# How to capture menu selection events

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to expand all collapsed rows of a table when user tries to search for a string using Ctrl + F or using menu item Find. I am able to do this when user hits Ctrl + F, but not sure how to achieve the same when user selects menu item Find.

```
$('body').keydown(function(e){
  if(e.ctrlKey && e.which == 70){
    $(expandAll());
  }
});

function expandAll() {
    $("#resultDetails tr").each(function(){
        if ($(this).hasClass('expand')) 
           $(this).removeClass('expand').addClass('collapse');
        $(this).show();
    });
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/R3Jy7/3/). How can I capture the browser menu item events.

Thoughts.

Comment: you won't be able to since it falls outside the scope of the document loaded in the browser. Same reason why it's difficult detecting back button or refresh clicks and have to resort to unload events to check

Comment: @DhavalMarthak Dhaval, If I am searching for a string using Ctrl + F or using menu item Find and if any row is hidden/collapsed (and if this hidden row contains the required string), then browser will not be able to find the required string as its hidden. So my idea is to capture the Ctrl+F event and expand all the rows. With above code, I am able to capture the Ctrl+F. Same thing I want to achieve when user uses menu item Find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is NO way you can listen to browser events, the only thing you can do is the thing that you already did, subscribing to the keyup and keydown events only.
You can NOT hook on the search browser function.

Answer (score 1):

Just run the function like this:

```
$('body').keydown(function(e){
  if(e.ctrlKey && e.which == 70){
    expandAll(); //no need to use jQuery way
  }
});
```

As per your comment:

```
//run the function on click event:

$('.your-menu').on('click',expandAll);
```

Comment: I have already done this and able to capture Ctrl + F, but want to do the same when user uses menu item Find instead of Ctrl+F.

Comment: Your fix will work on customized menu, but I want to capture the browser menu item (Ex. For IE, Edit --> Find on this page ).

Comment: whatever, apply the function there.

Answer (score 0):

Use this javascript code no need to use any jquery

```
    document.onkeydown = function (e) {

        // check ctrl + f key
        if (e.ctrlKey === true && e.keyCode === 70) {

            e.preventDefault();

           //alert('Ctrl + f was hit...');

             $(expandAll());

            return false;
        }
```