# How do you capture Mac menu bar selections in javascript?

Tags: javascript, macos, menu

I need to perform a select-all in my web app.  It is not for html form input elements but for elements I've drawn in a canvas.  I have no problem capturing the ctrl-A keypress, but I also need to capture the menu bar (top-of-screen) selection in a Mac when they choose Edit/Select-All.  I've googled like crazy but I can' find any general reference to capturing Mac menu bar actions in javascript.

This question ([How to capture menu selection events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22958059/how-to-capture-menu-selection-events)) asks the same thing for the Mac menu-item Find. The answer says specifically you can't capture find.  But can any other menu items like select-all be captured?

I'm using chrome.  Does chrome just assume app developers can't use Mac menu bar selections?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot capture browser events like this. Browser content (your webpage) is sandboxed inside of the browser to stop people from running code which can effect the browser (like taking over it, doing malicious things etc).

You'll have to simply do what you are doing and watch for the key presses.

As an aside, I imagine the percent of people that actually click that menu item is pretty small.

Comment: The user who reported this "bug" said they didn't know there was a keyboard shortcut for select-all.  They have always used the top menu-bar.  Go figure.

Comment: BTW, I tested a google doc word processor doc on Chrome and the menu bar select-all didn't work in that either.  If google can't make it work in their own browser then it must be impossible.  I'm surprised there aren't bug reports on this.  It just looks broken.

Comment: @mark-hahn its not a bug, its a feature. Old saying I know, but when you get into it, it is a security feature as I explained above. If you allow people to take over the browser functionality, they could run all sorts of things form web pages when the user doesn't want to! There is enough phishing going on without this! PS: If this solution is the answer to your question, please accept it so others may see it.